# Dynamically add rows to vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can you please help me how to add rows dynamically in vf page based on record getting in query in controller.
Below is the code i am using, in this currently adding one row, but need to add rows based on the records getting in SQL query.

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="ListsControllernew">
    <apex:form>   
        <apex:pageBlock title="Files">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
                <apex:commandButton value="Upload Files" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!oppname}" var="acc">
                <apex:column headerValue="Action" value="{!oppname}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Title" value="{!title}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Last Modified by" value="{!Modified}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Is Locked" value="{!Lockvalue}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class ListsControllernew  {

    private final Opportunity opp;
    public string title { get; set; }
    public String Modified { get; set; }
    public String Lockvalue { get; set; }
    public String oppname { get; set; }

    public ListsControllernew(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.opp = (Opportunity) stdController.getRecord();
        system.debug('id:'+opp.id);

        //List<Opportunity> customObjects =[select name from Opportunity where Id=:opp.id];
        //SELECT ContentDocumentId, FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = '[RECORD ID]' 

        integer count = [SELECT count() FROM ContentDocumentLink 
            WHERE LinkedEntityId =: opp.id];
        system.debug('Count:'+count);

        List<ContentDocumentLink> customObjects = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, 
            ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId, ContentDocument.Title, 
            ContentDocument.CreatedById, ContentDocument.LastModifiedDate FROM 
            ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: opp.id];

        for(ContentDocumentLink rec: customObjects) {
            oppname = rec.ContentDocument.Title;
            title = rec.ContentDocument.Title;
            Modified = rec.ContentDocument.CreatedById;
            Lockvalue = rec.ContentDocument.CreatedById;
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use a list of wrapper class to display information

Comment: new row entered/uploaded by from user or new rows added to database after page rendered? Wrapper pattern seemd like a good idea for the first assumed problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page block tables can be used with Collections, I've put together a quick example for you below:

Visualforce:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!documentLinks}" var="documentLink">
      <apex:column value="{!documentLink.ContentDocument.Title}" />
      <apex:column value="{!documentLink.ContentDocument.CreatedById}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Controller:

```
public class ObjectController {
     private final Opportunity opportunity;
     public List<ContentDocumentLink> documentLinks {get;set;}


     public ObjectController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
          opportunity = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
          records = [SELECT ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.CreatedById FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =: opportunity.id];
     }
}
```

Note: if you don't specify a header value for an SObject field, it should display the field's label.

Comment: i tried it , but i am getting error "Invalid field ContentDocumentId for SObject Opportunity"on trying to save vf page..any inputs pls?

Comment: Visu I've edited the example to make it a little more specific to your problem, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intention to display records linked to the opportunity record with which you opened the page? If so you have to give the pageblocktable the list of queried Items. Make customObjects a public variable and let the table use the queried List. You have to give each column a value of the CustomObject record.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customObjects}" var="obj">
    <apex:column headerValue="Title" value="{!obj.ContentDocument.Title}" />
    ...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Controller:

```
public List<ContentDocumentLink> customObjects {get; set;}
```